# Rails Engine serve and compile uploaded images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

I have a rails engine with a built-in file uploader allowing users to upload files to the engine.

If in the application production config config.assets.compile = true then I can see the uploaded images from the engine within the application views.

If config.assets.compile = false then the images from the engine are not available, even after I run assets:precompile ...

in the engine.rb I have set the following:

```
initializer :assets do |config|
    Rails.application.config.assets.paths << root.join("uploads", "my_engine")
end
```

any ideas?

thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that directory to the precompile list. This extra line should get it for you

```
initializer :assets do |app|
  app.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("uploads", "my_engine")
  app.config.assets.precompile << Rails.root.join("uploads", "my_engine", "*")
end
```

Comment: Hi Austio, thanks for the fast reply, unfortunately I now get the following: 

unknown filter type: #<Pathname:/path_to_engine/releases/20181128134247/uploads/my_engine

note the path exists